# Hide Parent Div if Child Table is hidden (display: none)

Tags: jquery, sugarcrm

I've tried searching all over StackOverflow and Google and I've found ideas that I thought would work but nothing seems to help!

I'm working in SugarCRM Professional 6.5.5 and I'm trying to hide the parent div of a child table if the table is hidden (display: none) using jQuery but I'm not having much luck.

For example, in the code below I'm trying to hide `<div id="detailpanel_5" class="detail view detail508 expanded">` because the child table `<table id="LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6" class="panelContainer" cellspacing="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 0px; display: none;">` is hidden.

I am able to successfully hide the parent div with `$('#LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6').parent().hide();` however the problem is that there are a lot of tables hidden on each page, and the view is dynamic -- not every page will have the same tables hidden.

So what I want jQuery to do is go through the page after it is loaded and hide only the parent div of the child table that is hidden.

I've tried using something like: `$(":hidden").parent().hide();` to search for any hidden elements but that hides the entire page (the screen is completely white).  I've tried `$("table:hidden").parent().hide();` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Apologies if I left out any details that would be needed to help with an answer.  I will be glad to offer any more info if it is needed.  Hopefully it's something very small I am overlooking.

A small snippet of the HTML is below:

```
<div class="yui-content">
    <div id="tabcontent0">
        <div id="detailpanel_1" class="detail view detail508 ">
        <div id="detailpanel_2" class="detail view detail508 expanded">
        <div id="detailpanel_3" class="detail view detail508 expanded">
        <div id="detailpanel_4" class="detail view detail508 expanded">
            <h4>
            <table id="LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL7" class="panelContainer" cellspacing="0">
            <script type="text/javascript">
        </div>
        <div id="detailpanel_5" class="detail view detail508 expanded">
            <h4>
            <table id="LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6" class="panelContainer" cellspacing="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 0px; display: none;">
```

Comment: I'm still trying to work this out.  I tried `$('table[style]').parent().hide()` to see if it will hide all of the parent elements of tables with the style attribute but it does not work.  However, when trying `$('table[id]').parent().hide();` it works.  `$('table[cellspacing]'.parent().hide();` also works, but these hide many elements that I don't want hidden.  It's as if jQuery isn't seeing that the tables even have a style attribute, which is probably why the `$('table:hidden').parent().hide();` isn't working.  I wonder what's going on here... hmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(":hidden")` returns the `<head>`, `<style>`, `<script>` ,etc elements also. Their parent is the `<html>` document itself. So naturally `$(":hidden").parent().hide();` will hide the entire document. Therefore you must be a bit more specific.

As told by @denisk `$('table:hidden').parent().hide();` should work perfectly.

*In the code you have shown, it didn't work probably because of the `<h4>` tags.*

Comment: Unfortunately `$('table:hidden').parent().hide();` does not work still.  The parent div of the hidden table is still showing.  Perhaps it something specific with SugarCRM or that part of the page where the code in my original post is being loaded through AJAX by the CRM? I'm really not sure.  `$('table[id=<ID OF TABLE TO HIDE>]).parent().hide();` works fine and I can write multiple statements to hide the parent div one-by-one, but unfortunately that will take a while to write all of that in.  I'll keep looking!  Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':hidden').parent().hide();
```

should work: http://jsfiddle.net/UtGM3/

Comment: I tried that myself, but it seems to be hiding everything on the page.  When I refresh/reload the page, the entire screen is white/hidden.  Is there anything I can do to modify that statement so it just hides the parent "above" the table in the DOM?

Comment: `$('table:hidden').parent().hide();` does the trick for me: http://jsfiddle.net/UtGM3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Because you are setting css display to none

```
$('table').each(function(){
if ($(this).css("display") == "none")
{
$(this).parent().hide();
}
})
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be hiding anything, unfortunately.  The parent divs of all of the hidden tables are still showing.

Comment: sorry i missed the paranteses, hope you dint. ill go through ur code again, this is interesting

Comment: There is quite a bit more inside the <tbody> but I left that out due to character limit on comments. `<div id="detailpanel_5" class="detail view detail508 expanded">
    <h4>
    <table id="LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL6" class="panelContainer" cellspacing="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 0px; display: none;">
        <tbody>
    </table>`

Comment: From my understanding of the DOM, <h4> is a sibling of <table>.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18238/discussion-between-merrick-dennis-and-i-love-php)